# jquery autocomplete failing for new TRs

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

We have a VERY bizarre condition with https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete.

When we add a new TR to our html table, 2 out of 3 autocomplete input-tags work great but the 3rd one is failing (that is, it does not present the values)

The failing input-tag is missing:

```
     class="ui-autocomplete-input"
```

HOWEVER, we have added that class using:

```
 $(this).addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
```

and it's still failing!

Has anyone encountered this type of behavior?

Comment: You will often see this behavior when the event listener is not applied properly and therefore does not get triggered by any new elements added after the DOM bound the event listener.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, do you mean that the first TR gets the ui-autocomplete-input class applied when added, by any subsequent TRs don't?

Comment: Hi Ryan --- regarding  (1) "event listener is not applied properly" -- yes we have a javascript function that contains all 3 event listeners, which is called after each ajax call;  (2) "do you mean that the first TR gets the ui-autocomplete-input class applied when added, by any subsequent TRs don't?"  -- yes essentially correct, only that the first 2 TRs have the ui-autocomplete-input class and the 3rd does not

Comment: Try using console.log($(this)); at the same location as the $(this).addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" ) line. It could be that the loop that applies that class is referring to the same control each iteration.

Comment: Yes excellent suggestion.  I had already tried that ... in addition I have a button that displays the event-listeners and they are well-formed.

Comment: I have not "admitted defeat" yet, but am going to walk-away from this until at least tomorrow

Comment: If you'd like to post some more of your code, in a jsfiddle or something, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hi Again Ryan  -- OK after a "distraction" I'm back to looking at this issue.   We've identified that the following function defeats the AutoComplete columns but ONLY after the SearchButton.click() is run a 2nd time.

Comment: please see      https://jsfiddle.net/ConradKrinock/pcwb8ne9/   The trace logging definitively affirms that the function runs successfully on both the 1st and 2nd runs of SearchButton.Click() !?!??!?!?!

Comment: That fiddle appears to only have the Javascript and I don't see any logic for SearchButton.Click(), is that in the html element, if so, what does it call?